# three rows of md-8 + one long vertical of md-4 (next to all three rows)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

```
    <body>
```

This section should be on the right of all three rows as md-4 columns that are vertically the height of the three rows to the left.

> TEXT
>
> ```
>                     <form action="php" class=
>                     "form-contact" data-ajax-fail-msg=
>                     "Ajax could not set the request"
>                     data-all-fields-required-msg="All fields are required"
>                     data-success-msg="Email successfully sent." id=
>                     "contact-form-agent" method="post" name=
>                     "contact-form-agent">
>                         <input name="name" placeholder="Full Name" type="text">
>                         <input name="email" placeholder="E-mail" type="text">
>                         <input name="title" placeholder="Title" type="text">
>                         <input name="company" placeholder="Company" type=
>                         "text"> 
>
>                         <textarea name="message" placeholder=
>                         "Tell us What Keeps You Up At Night">
> </textarea> <input class="submit-alt pull-right" type="submit"
>                         value="Get Started">
>
>                         <p class="return-msg">
>                         </p>
>                     </form>
>                 </div>
> ```

Above is the code for the submit fields to enter for the php.
Below is the 2nd md-4 image under the form submit fields.

> ```
>                 <div class="col-md-4 onscroll-animate" data-animation=
>                 "fadeInUp">
>                     <br>
>                     <br>
>                     <a href=""><img alt="" height=
>                     "190" src="images/assets/video-thumb-A.png" width=
>                     "331"></a>
>
>                     <h3>SEE FOR YOURSELF</h3>
>                     <br>
>                 </div>
>             </div>
>         </div>
>     </section>
> ```

This section is the three rows as md-8 completing the 12 row bootstrap columns.

> ```
>     <section>
>         <div class="section-content">
>             <div class="container">
>                 <section id="listings-section">
>                     <div class="section-content">
>                         <div class="section-header onscroll-animate"
>                         data-animation="fadeInLeft">
>                             <p>TEXT</p>
>                         </div>
>
>
>                         <div class="row">
>                             <div class="col-md-12">
>                                 <div class="profile">
>                                     <div class="row">
>                                         <div class="col-xs-4">
>                                             <div class="profile-img"><img alt=
>                                             "store-icon" src=
>                                             "images/icons/store-icon.png">
>                                             </div>
>                                         </div>
>
>
>                                         <div class=
>                                         "col-xs-8 text-left onscroll-animate"
>                                         data-animation="fadeInUp">
>                                             <h5 class="profile-heading">
>                                             </h5>
>
>
>                                             <p>
>                                             </p>
>
>
>                                             <div class="profile-cotent">
>                                                 <h3 class=
>                                                 "section-small-heading">TEXT</h3>
>                                             </div>
>                                         </div>
>                                     </div>
>                                     <!-- .row -->
>                                 </div>
>                                 <!-- .profile -->
>                             </div>
>                             <!-- .col-md-8 -->
>                         </div>
>                         <!-- .row -->
>                     </div>
>                     <!-- .section-content -->
>                 </section>
>
>
>                 <div class="section-header onscroll-animate" data-animation=
>                 "fadeInLeft">
>                     <p>TEXT</p>
>                 </div>
>
>
>                 <div class="col-md-12">
>                     <div class="profile">
>                         <div class="row">
>                             <div class="col-xs-4">
>                                 <div class="profile-img"><img alt="hand-icon"
>                                 src="images/icons/hand-icon.png">
>                                 </div>
>                             </div>
>
>
>                             <div class="col-xs-8 text-left onscroll-animate"
>                             data-animation="fadeInUp">
>                                 <h5 class="profile-heading">
>                                 </h5>
>
>
>                                 <p>
>                                 </p>
>
>
>                                 <div class="profile-cotent">
>                                     <h3 class="section-small-heading">TEXT</h3>
>                                 </div>
>                             </div>
>                         </div>
>                         <!-- .row -->
>                     </div>
>                     <!-- .profile -->
>                 </div>
>                 <!-- .col-md-12 -->
>                 <!--AMP SECTION 3-->
>
>                 <div class="section-header onscroll-animate" data-animation=
>                 "fadeInLeft">
>                     <p>TEXT</p>
>                 </div>
>
>
>                 <div class="col-md-12">
>                     <div class="profile">
>                         <div class="row">
>                             <div class="col-xs-4">
>                                 <div class="profile-img"><img alt="store-icon"
>                                 src="images/icons/computer-icon.png">
>                                 </div>
>                             </div>
>
>
>                             <div class="col-xs-8 text-left onscroll-animate"
>                             data-animation="fadeInUp">
>                                 <h5 class="profile-heading">
>                                 </h5>
>
>
>                                 <div class="profile-cotent">
>                                     <h3 class="section-small-heading">TEXT</h3>
>                                 </div>
>                             </div>
>                         </div>
>                         <!-- .row -->
>                     </div>
>                     <!-- .profile -->
>                 </div>
>                 <!-- .col-md-12 -->
>
>
>                 <div class="col-md-12">
>                     <div class="profile">
>                         <div class="row">
>                             <div class="profile-cotent">
>                                 <h3 class="section-small-heading">TEXT</h3>
>                             </div>
>                         </div>
>                     </div>
>                     <!-- .row -->
>                 </div>
>                 <!-- .profile -->
>             </div>
>             <!-- .col-md-12 -->
>         </div>
>     </section>
>     <!-- .col-md-3 -->
>     <!-- .row -->
>     <!-- .container -->
>     <!-- .section-content -->
> ```

Please help and thank you.

```
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your basic nested row should do:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12"> ... </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12"> ... </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12"> ... </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"> ... </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

Comment: why are none of the <div class="col-xs-8"> and xs-4 not contained within sections?

Comment: Because those aren't necessary to demonstrate the solution. You're expected to add all your markup to this outline.